# Driver detected a controller error

Tags: backup

We have a Server running Windows Server 2008 R2 with an external HDD (1TB) for backup purposes. The external HDD is fine and working but I wonder every week I got an error saying

**"The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk3\DR15."**

﻿﻿I've already updated the driver for the said HDD and it says its running the updated driver for it.

Should I worry and get a new HDD as replacement for this?

Your thoughts please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have an exclamation points/error icons in Device Manager. To get to Device Manager: Log in as an administrative user -> Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Device Manager.

Quite possibly you might have to replace your HDD.

Comment: So far the external HDD is working fine, I can open and restore from backup with no problem. I can say its still 100% functionality.  There is no yellow exclamation on device manager and the HDD has the driver installed on it. I just wonder why I keep receiving this error on my logs.